# How to add new Cordova lifecycle events?

Tags: android, cordova

[Cordova lifecycle events](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events) can be used in PhoneGap applications. How to add new device events to this list? I'm thinking specifically of Android's Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON / SCREEN_OFF.